# Ember Routing Model Observing Updates in Handlebars Template

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

How do I update a model property once a promise (via Ajax call) has returned? Here is my go at it that is not working. In the docs, it appears observing takes place using Ember.set but the model I am returning is not an Ember model object so I don't think that works.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({

    model: function() {

        var model = { title: "Lorem Ipsum" };
        var userSubscriptions = [];
        var App = this;

        Ember.$.getJSON('http://localhost:1337/company/usersubscription/active/', parameters, function(userSubscriptions) {

            userSubscriptions.forEach(function(data) {

                var userSubscription = App.store.push('usersubscription', data);
                userSubscriptions.pushObject(userSubscription);

                model.title   = "No Lorem Ipsum";
                model.objects = userSubscriptions;

            });

        });

        return model;

    }

});
```

Comment: What's the reason for not using an `Ember.Object`, what do you try to achieve and what is not working in detail?

Comment: I'm kind of confused as how to go about doing so using Ember CLI.

Comment: You simply can use http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Object.html#method_create like this: `var model = Ember.Object.create({title: "Lorem Ipsum"});`. But it seems that you are fighting a bit against the framework. If you could explain what you try to do more in detail, then maybe I or someone else can help you more.

Comment: @kunerd, I agree. It seems I am fighting it. All I want to do is pass other values from my route to the template. An example of why I would want to do this is to display messages when there are errors, issues, no results, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `model = Ember.Object.create({title: 'old Title'})`, then you can use `model.set('title', 'new Title')` to set a new title, that will be updated on the view automatically.

Here is a simple example JSBin:  http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xuzevizabe/2/edit

But it seems that you instead want to use ember-data to handle your models.

Comment: Thank you for bringing some clarity to Ember :)

Comment: Could you shed some light on the following error I am receiving? It only happens on some routes. The suggestion works but I do not want to wrap the model in an array. Error while processing route: shipments.unshipped Assertion Failed: ArrayController expects `model` to implement the Ember.Array mixin. This can often be fixed by wrapping your model with `Ember.A()`. Error: Assertion Failed: ArrayController expects `model` to implement the Ember.Array mixin. This can often be fixed by wrapping your model with `Ember.A()`.

Comment: Ember.ArrayController and Ember.ObjectController are deprecated. You should not be using them.